# Sort non-unique names by sum of another column

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet (technically a Google Sheet) I transcribed from a script of a musical. Each line is its own row, and has the name of the person who said it and the number of words in the line in the same row.

I want to make a list of people who have lines sorted by the total number of words they've said. What functions can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing people's names appear multiple times, so suggest a [pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

[image: WA108271 example]

`Bod` added to ROWS and `Words` added to VALUES with Summarise by SUM.

Sorting is by `Bod` by default but can be by Sum of Words, either ascending or descending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort functionality from the Data menu, if it's a one-time thing, or the `=SORT()` function.